# Free-flight camera with vectors - how to rotate properly?

Tags: java, opengl, camera, lwjgl

I have this camera that is set up with `vecmath.lookatMatrix(eye, center, up)`.
The movement works fine, forwards, backwards, right, left, these work fine.
What does not seem to work fine is the rotation.

I am not really good at math, so I assume I may be missing some logic here, but I thought the rotation would work like this:
On rotation around the **Y-axis** I add/sub a value to the **X value** of the center vector.
On rotation around the **X-axis I** add/sub a value to the **Y value** of the center vector.
For example here is rotation to the right: `center = center.add(vecmath.vector(turnSpeed, 0, 0))`

This actually works, but with some strange behaviour. It looks like the higher the x/y of the center vector value gets, the slower the rotation. I guess it's because through the addition/substraction to the center vector it moves too far away or something similar, I would really like to know what is actually happening.

Actually while writing this, I just realized this can't work like this, because once I have moved around and rotated a bit, and for example I'm in "mid air", the rotation would be wrong....

I really hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution to working with a free-flight camera with eye, center, up vectors was posted here:
[Free Flight Camera - strange rotation around X-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835641/free-flight-camera-strange-rotation-around-x-axis/25847482#25847482)

Answer (score 1):

Rotating a vector for OpenGL should be done using [matrices](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html). Linear movement can be executed by simply adding vectors together, but for rotation it is not enough just to change one of the coordinates... if that was the case, how'd you get from (X,0,0) direction to (0,X,0)?
[Here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/) is another tutorial, which is C++, but there are Java samples too.
There is a bit of math behind all this - you seem to be familiar with vectors, and probably have a 'feel' of them, which helps.
EDIT - if you are to use matrices in OpenGL properly, you'll need to familiarize yourself with the [MVP concepts](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). You have something to display (the model) which is placed somewhere in your world (view) at which you are looking through a camera (projection).

Comment: Hm, tank you that first article seems interesting.
From what I understood I need to multiply the vector between eye and center with a rotationmatrix?
Just to make clear what I mean: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_ltmZpULxXtI/TSZll_0SASI/AAAAAAAAAeY/nal05L9OOm4/s320/gluLookAt_camera.png   

I just tried that but I think I failed....

Comment: I have added a link to my answer, check that out.

Comment: I tried to work with these matrices and it kind of worked half-way, it only worked around the Y-axis but not thex-Axis and I don't know if this was a bad move from me but I posted that "new" problem as a new question. But someone helped me there, so I'll post a link to that answer as an answer here.
I hope this is ok with you, I am really glad you tried to help me and I'll upvote your answer.