# Free Flight Camera - strange rotation around X-axis

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation, lwjgl, rotational-matrices

So I nearly implemented a free-flight camera using vectors and something like gluLookAt.
The movement in all 4 directions and rotation around the Y-axis work fine.

For the **rotation around the Y-axis** I calculate the vector between the eye and center vector and then rotate it with the rotation matrix like this:

```
      Vector temp = vecmath.vector(center.x() - eye.x(),
                    center.y() - eye.y(), center.z() - eye.z());

     float vecX = (temp.x()*(float) Math.cos(-turnSpeed)) + (temp.z()* (float)Math.sin(-turnSpeed));
     float vecY = temp.y();
     float vecZ = (temp.x()*(float) -Math.sin(-turnSpeed))+ (temp.z()*(float)Math.cos(-turnSpeed));

     center = vecmath.vector(vecX, vecY, vecZ);
```

At the end I just set center to the newly calculated vector.
Now when I try to do the same thing for **rotation around the X-axis** it DOES rotate the vector but in a very strange way, kind of like it would be moving in a wavy line.
I use the same logic as for the previous rotation, just with the x rotation matrix:

```
     Vector temp = vecmath.vector(center.x() - eye.x(),
                            center.y() - eye.y(), center.z() - eye.z());

     float vecX = temp.x();
     float vecY = (temp.y()*(float) Math.cos(turnSpeed)) + (temp.z()* (float)-Math.sin(turnSpeed));
     float vecZ = (temp.y()*(float) Math.sin(turnSpeed)) + (temp.z()*(float)Math.cos(turnSpeed));

     center = vecmath.vector(vecX, vecY, vecZ);
```

But why does this not work? Maybe I do something else somewhere wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to make the camera movement work like in most first person games? i.e. the up vector always point "up" in world space?

Comment: @bofjas Well like a FPS camera but more, it has to "fly" too, not only move on the ground. 
Oh...Would the camera pointing slightly upwards already distort that up vector? Yea....it's not pointing upwards anymore, so I have to calculate the upvector too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is the exact same that I had trouble with the first time I tried to implement the camera movement. The problem occurs because if you first turn so that you are looking straight down the X axis and then try to "tilt" the camera by rotating around the X axis, you will effectively actually spin around the direction you are looking.

I find that the best way to handle camera movement is to accumulate the angles in separate variables and every time rotate completely from origin. If you do this you can first "tilt" by rotating around the X-axis then turn by rotating around the Y-axis. By doing it in this order you make sure that the tilting will always be around the correct axis relative to the camera. Something like this:

```
public void pan(float turnSpeed)
{
    totalPan += turnSpeed;

    updateOrientation();
}

public void tilt(float turnSpeed)
{
    totalTilt += turnSpeed;

    updateOrientation();
}

private void updateOrientation()
{
     float afterTiltX = 0.0f; // Not used. Only to make things clearer
     float afterTiltY = (float) Math.sin(totalTilt));
     float afterTiltZ = (float) Math.cos(totalTilt));

     float vecX = (float)Math.sin(totalPan) * afterTiltZ;
     float vecY = afterTiltY;
     float vecZ = (float)Math.cos(totalPan) * afterTiltZ;

     center = eye + vecmath.vector(vecX, vecY, vecZ); 
}
```

I don't know if the syntax is completely correct. Haven't programmed in java in a while.

Comment: Wow you are awesome, it works perfectly! But I'm afraid I don't fully understand the full logic, since I am not that good in math, maybe there is some article or tutorial you read about this? I would like to understand this.

Comment: I don't have any specific links unfortunately. I would suggest reading up on cos and sin if those are unclear. But basically a unrotated camera would have center be straight in the z direction from eye. When we tilt, more and more from z axis is moved over to y until you reach 90 degrees and there is 0.0 left on the z axis. This is what we are doing with the first three lines. After that we do the exact same thing with the z component of the vector we just constructed. the y component is unmodified since we are rotating around the Y axis. It's hard to explain in a comment. Best of luck!

Comment: Hm, thank you for the explanation, I think I actually understood this a little bit now.
But right now there's a little problem with that rotation. When I rotate for the first time, it kind of spins my vectors or something, so I have to hold E or Q and rotate it back to the old view, and when I don't start with the Y rotation but the X rotation it reverses the order, so the UP button becomes DOWN and so on, but if I start with the Y rotation the X rotation works fine.
Maybe I could initialize the view in some way so that I have already rotated it and can adjust the view to look normal again?

Comment: By the way I initialize the vectors like this: eye = vecmath.vector(0f, 0f, 10f); center = vecmath.vector(0f, 0f, 0f);

Comment: Ah disregard my previous comments, I didn't think far enough!
I just had to initialize the pan and tilt variables with the values that come out after the first calculation with the matrices, so I just set totalPan to -3, not 0 like first, and it works!

Thank you again, you really helped me.